# Why is webpack looking for jQuery when the module doesn't require it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I'd like to preface this question by saying it is hard for me to understand what exactly is going on in this issue and I apologise if it's not up to Stackoverflow's Q&A standards.

I'm trying to `import` an NPM module that's then compiled by Webpack on our project. [This](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper) is the module in question, and [this](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/dist/js/swiper.js) is the file that's giving us problems.

At the end of that file, there is the export code:

```
if (typeof(module) !== 'undefined')
{
    module.exports = window.Swiper;
}
else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], function () {
        'use strict';
        return window.Swiper;
    });
}
```

And that's it. Throughout the file there are some references to `jQuery` but nothing that suggests webpack should include it as a module. Do a search for `"jQuery"` and see for yourself.

So why is it then when we import the plugin like so:

`import Swiper from 'swiper'`

We get the following error? [image]

No where else in the module's `package.json` or similar does it describe jQuery as a dependency. I have no idea what's happening. If it's any use, here is the code that seems to throw the error in the compiled bundle:

```
else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], function () {
            'use strict';
            return window.Swiper;
        });
    }
    //# sourceMappingURL=maps/swiper.js.map

    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"jquery\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()))))
```

Comment: It appears that your assumptions regarding how webpack determines dependencies are incorrect...  The swiper source code references jQuery, which may or may not be optional, but webpack can not make that determination without help.

Answer (score 0):

I think Swiper itself requires jQuery. Because you are in an AMD/webpack environment, Swiper is trying to "import/require" it and webpack cannot find it.

Comment: I have used Swiper without jQuery successfully. Swiper is built to be library agnostic and I have used it without jQuery successfully outside of AMD environments

Comment: As you can see in the first error stack, swiper.js on line 5333 is trying to load it. Might be a version thing.