# Why do I need a special "hack" for jQuery when using Bootstrap with Webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack

My original question was solved by reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825936/jquery-is-not-defined-when-using-webpack-to-load-bootstrap?noredirect=1&lq=1), but since I want to understand the whole webpack system, I ask myself:

Why do I have to do this? (Import jQuery myself and explicitly include it in some way in the webpack config)

Shouldn't webpack find jQuery as a dependency of bootstrap and add it, when I import bootstrap? I just don't understand why there is so much happening automagically, but this is breaking without me hacking something into my webpack config.

This is basically my setup:

- cloned the angular2 seed which uses webpack: https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed
- installed bootstrap package:
  npm install bootstrap --save ( => "bootstrap": "^3.3.7")
- imported the bootstrap css in my app.component.ts:
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

The css seems to be imported just fine, but I get this "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" (at run time) which also appears in the thread mentioned above.

My question is admittedly a similar one to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488896/why-is-webpack-looking-for-jquery-when-the-module-doesnt-require-it) but I don't think the answers have been really convincing.

When modules use jQuery, shouldn't they import jQuery in some way?

Or, asked in another way: If I get this runtime error, doesn't it mean the contrib module's devs worked a bit dirty?

Please consider that I am

- new to 1. stackoverflow, 2. webpack
- quite new to modular JavaScript
- not interested in a concrete problem being solved, rather than in general enlightenment regarding this topic

Thanks in advance

Cheers
Sören

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree. The bootstrap PR [#16534 CommonJS: require() jQuery if not already loaded](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/16534) tried to change the behaviour (i.e., automatically `require` jQuery unless present), but has been closed since no more development is happening for bootstrap 3.